# Optimizing a slow performing redis db

Tags: redis

I have a 2.7GB redis database (that's the size of the dump file) - I'm running on a server with huge memory (64GB) and not much else on there. The redis performance isn't great (sometimes takes ~5s to retrieve a hash via the redis-cli tool on the box). Can anyone help with :-

1. How can I tell that the db is being processed in memory as opposed to swapping/reading off the disk ?
2. Any optimization tips to speed up performance ?

I should add this is essentially a read-only db.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: what can you tell us about the host OS?

Comment: What else is talkin to the redis instance? What version? What are your disk save settings? We need to know more about your setup before we can answer.

Comment: What data structures do you use? If you extensively use hashes, then there are settings that can fine tune a lot. Dunno if thats also the case with other data structures

Answer (score 1):

- The 2.7GB RDB file size isn't a good indicator of your dataset's size - what does `INFO` say about your `used_memory`?
- 5s is a very long time to retrieve anything from Redis - check your `SLOWLOG` to see what operations are slowing down your performance (and for > 2.8.13 latency doctor as well)
- re. swapping - disable swapping entirely by setting `vm.swappiness=0` and `vm.overcommit_memory=1`

Furthermore, by adding the output of `INFO ALL` the kind folks here would potentially be able to provide more assistance regarding possible optimizations.